# Local network accessible but not internet via ethernet card (happens in Windows AND Ubuntu (dual boot) on same machine). What has happened to card?

Tags: ethernet, internet-connection, local, connection, limited-access

I have a desktop PC with a 1Gb ethernet card as well as a built-in motherboard 100mb/s ethernet card.

Very recently, internet access using these has stopped working. Initially I thought it was a problem with the Windows 7 Home 32bit edition I have installed but the same problem occurs when the machine is booted into Ubuntu 11.

Local network is still available as I can mount a network share with them. But no internet.

This leads me to believe that there is a problem with the ethernet card and the ethernet on the motherboard. Is there a BIOS-like or other non-volatile storage or settings that could have changed on these.

It is also a coincidence that both have failed at the same time.

On the same machine, in Windows 7, a wireless USB receiver stick can receive internet from my ADSL router's wireless. So internet can work on the installation.

Thoughts about what might have happened to the wired-ethernet card and onboard ethernet?

**Update**

Further detail (apologies for not giving this earlier):

- A MacBookPro works with internet OK, it is connected to same bridge as desktop (this is why I thought it is a problem with the desktop card or built-in port rather than my general internet connectivity)
- Bridges are a 4 port XyZel
- Modem is Thompson speedtouch 580 ADSL

```
Topology:
---------

Spare room:                                    Lounge room:   

                                    +---+      +---+    +-------+
Ubuntu 11/Windows 7 32bit home------+ B |      | B +----+ Modem +-----> DSL line
                                    | r |      | r |    +-------+
MacBookPro -------------------------+ i +------+ i |               +------+
                                    | d |      | d +---------------+ NAS  +
Toshiba NB100 ----------------------+ g |      | g |    +--------+ +------+
                                    | e |      | e +----+ Settop |
                                    +---+      +---+    +--------+
```

**NOTE**

I think there is something perhaps more serious with the desktop - it shutdown on its own accord last night. Not wishing to waste your time but if it is OK but still can't connect then this question is still valid so input is welcome.

Comment: You forgot to describe the problem. What happens when you try to access the Internet? Can you ping by IP address? Does DNS work?

Comment: Can you ping your Outward Bound Gateway (ie your Router)?

Comment: Are these powerline bridges or WiFi bridges? If Wifi, are they in WDS mode? If powerline, where is the WiFi coming from? My bet is that this is a bridging issue. The Wifi option works because it avoids the bridging.

Comment: +1 @DavidSchwartz they are standard ordinary ethernet wired links.

Comment: @therobyouknow So there is no WiFi or powerline in the path at all? It's wired all the way from the PC to the DSL?

Comment: yes, correct. But as mentioned in original answer I then used a wifi usb stick to connect the problematic desktop PC to the speedtouch 580 modem directly, just to see if the desktop could get on the internet at all. But after that I removed the usb wifi stick to go back to the original set up as described and continued to attempt to troubleshoot.

Comment: ALL FINE NOW - but DON'T know why. Thanks for your time so far particularly @David Schwartz. I will leave it for a day or so in case the problem comes back. After if still OK that I will either self-answer or vote for delete. Thanks again.

Comment: I suspect it was a 'glitch' of some kind on the ADSL modem about allocating IP addresses to machines. There is a significant chance it is this especially given that internet wasn't available but local network was on both Windows and Ubuntu.